# Reportserver with Postgres under Tomcat 9 installation issue

Tags: postgresql, tomcat9, reportserver

I'm trying to install Reportserver  under Tomcat 9 with PostgreSQL.

Everything goes fine until I'm running the Tomcat server  and I get this log:

DB Config:

```
hibernate.dialect: net.datenwerke.rs.utils.hibernate.PostgreSQLDialect (OK)
hibernate.connection.driver_class: org.postgresql.Driver (OK)
hibernate.connection.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reportserver (OK)
hibernate.connection.username: ****_user
hibernate.connection.password: ********
hibernate.default_schema: 
Connection Test: OK
Schema Version: RS3.0-14
```

Application Server: Apache Tomcat/9.0.30

PAM Configuration

```
Static PAM configuration: 
    net.datenwerke.rs.authenticator.service.pam.UserPasswordPAMAuthoritative
Finalized PAM configuration: class 
    net.datenwerke.rs.authenticator.service.pam.UserPasswordPAMAuthoritative
```

```
11:35:51.451 ERROR n.d.r.c.s.i.InternalDbStartup - Error in Internal DB Startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at net.datenwerke.dbpool.DbC3p0PoolServiceImpl$1.get(DbC3p0PoolServiceImpl.java:189) ~[reportserver.jar:na]
at net.datenwerke.dbpool.DbC3p0PoolServiceImpl$1.get(DbC3p0PoolServiceImpl.java:1) ~[reportserver.jar:na]
at net.datenwerke.rs.core.service.internaldb.TempTableServiceImpl.dropRSTMPtables(TempTableServiceImpl.java:69) ~[reportserver.jar:na]
at net.datenwerke.rs.core.service.internaldb.InternalDbStartup$1.initialize(InternalDbStartup.java:45) ~[reportserver.jar:na]
at net.datenwerke.gf.service.lateinit.LateInitStartup$1.run(LateInitStartup.java:62) [reportserver.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:211) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
      at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1127) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
      at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1114) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
      at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
      at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1855) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
      at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.9.jar:0.2.9]
11:35:51.845 INFO  n.d.r.s.s.search.SearchServiceImpl - Rebuilding search index...
11:35:52.085 INFO  n.d.r.c.s.i.RemoteMessageServiceImpl - Available locales: de, hi, lo, pt, lt, hr, lv, hu, zh-CN, hy, uk, id, mk, mn, af, uz, ms, el, mt, en, is, it, my, es, et, eu, vi, ja, ne, ro, nl, no, be, fi, ru, bg, keys, bn, fr, jw, bs, ka, si, sk, sl, ga, gd, ca, sq, sr, kk, km, sv, ko, zh-TW, ta, cs, th, lb, tl, pl, da, tr
11:35:53.406 INFO  n.d.g.s.lateinit.LateInitStartup - Startup completed
```

Does any one have a clue? I added the postgresql-42.2.9.jre7.jar to the lib folder on the ROOT folder and still same issue.

Comment: `jre7.jar` is intended for Java 7  - which Java version are you using?

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for the reply, i'm using java 8 Update 231

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still having this problem: it is caused because of the ReportServer internal datasource, which is not the same as the values found in the persistence.properties file. Normally, persistence.properties and your internal datasource should contain the same values, but in your case they seem to be different, so you should fix this:

You should first remove the driver you added manually (postgresql-42.2.9.jre7.jar), as [ReportServer](https://reportserver.net/) already ships with a appropriate Postgres driver, and then configure your internal DB as explained [here](https://reportserver.net/en/guides/config/chapters/Datasources/):

> ReportServer uses a database to buffer data coming from non-database
> datasources such as, for example, CSV datasources. This buffer
> database is called the internal database. Per default ReportServer
> uses the its own database for this and creates tables with the prefix
> rs_tmptbl_. You can change the database to be used as well as
> configure certain aspects of the internal database via the
> configuration file datasources/internaldb.cf. The default
> configuration file is
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>    <internaldb>
>       <droponstartup>true</droponstartup>
>       <datasource>ReportServer Data Source</datasource>
>    </internaldb>
> </configuration>
> ```